# Webpack error from UglifyJS when creating production assets

Tags: javascript, jquery, webpack, webpack-encore

I am using Webpack Encore (similar to Webpack) to create asset files.
Everything works well when creating the development files, however when running to command to generate the minified files for production I get an error.

> ERROR  Failed to compile with 1 errors
>   app.js from UglifyJS .
>   Invalid assignment [app.js:131,42]
>   Unexpected character '`' [app.js:10953,9]

It seems like the issue is caused by two plugins:

jquery-asScrollable and jquery-asScrollbar
In fact commenting out the following lines, the process completes successfully

```
require('jquery-asScrollable');
require('jquery-asScrollbar');
```

**My package.json file**

```
{
  "devDependencies": {
    "@symfony/webpack-encore": "^0.17.1",
    "animsition": "^4.0.2",
    "bootstrap": "4.0.0-beta.2",
    "jquery": "^3.2.1",
    "jquery-asScrollable": "^0.4.10",
    "jquery-asScrollbar": "^0.5.7",
    "jquery-mousewheel": "^3.1.13",
    "node-sass": "^4.7.2",
    "popper.js": "^1.12.9",
    "sass-loader": "^6.0.6",
    "webpack-notifier": "^1.5.0"
  }
}
```

**UPDATE:**

**app.js**

```
require('jquery-asScrollable');
require('jquery-asScrollbar');
require('jquery-mousewheel');
```

Any ideas of what the problem might be?

Comment: Error points in app.js

Comment: can you show here your app.js

Comment: @Dipakchavda just updated my OP with the content of app.js

Comment: so probably you dig out more into this issue with the library or another I think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two plugins make use of ES6 syntax - in this case *template literals*. Uglify is incompatible with large parts of ES6. You need to either copy those plugins to your project code (so they get transpiled by your Babel) or un-exclude their respective node_modules folders in your Babel transpilation process.

See the template literals (and more ES6) being used [here](https://github.com/thecreation/jquery-asScrollable/blob/master/dist/jquery-asScrollable.es.js) (line 90-93):

[image: ES6 in plugin]

Another option is to import/require the **minified versions** of the plugins from their `dist` folders.

Example:

```
require('node_modules/jquery-asScrollable/dist/jquery-asScrollable.min.js')
```