# "gulp" command not compiling the program and throwing error

Tags: node.js, reactjs, gulp

I am trying to run gulp command in my nodejs react application. I am getting error and my program is failing to compile. Ubuntu the program compiles properly. I am running this on windows. I have already done npm install. All the loaders in webpack file also looks fine. This is the how I get the error

```
D:\tessact-client-2>gulp
[23:35:23] Requiring external module babel-register
[23:35:25] Using gulpfile D:\tessact-client-2\gulpfile.babel.js
[23:35:25] Starting 'build:watch'...
[23:35:25] Starting 'copy:assets'...
[23:35:25] Starting 'copy:vendors'...
  Cleaned build/
  Copied 14 asset entries.
[23:35:25] Finished 'copy:vendors' after 456 ms
[23:35:25] Starting 'copy:views'...
[23:35:25] copied views all files 1.79 kB
[23:35:25] Finished 'copy:views' after 45 ms
[23:35:25] Starting 'copy:public'...
[23:35:25] Finished 'copy:public' after 17 ms
[23:35:25] Finished 'copy:assets' after 527 ms
[23:35:25] Starting 'bundle:dll'...
DLL Bundled.
Hash: 53acb715dbdfb2d13d93
Version: webpack 1.13.3
Time: 40ms
        Asset     Size  Chunks             Chunk Names
dll.vendor.js  1.85 kB       0  [emitted]  vendor
[23:35:25] Finished 'bundle:dll' after 85 ms
[23:35:25] Starting 'bundle'...
Hash: 6444932e1774038f4027
Version: webpack 1.13.3
Time: 467ms
         Asset    Size  Chunks       Chunk Names
main-bundle.js  102 kB       0       main

ERROR in ./src/client/index.js
Module parse failed: D:\tessact-client-2\src\client\index.js Unexpected token (78:1)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
SyntaxError: Unexpected token (78:1)
    at Parser.pp$4.raise (D:\tessact-client-2\node_modules\webpack\node_modules\acorn\dist\acorn.js:2221:15)
    at Parser.pp.unexpected (D:\tessact-client-2\node_modules\webpack\node_modules\acorn\dist\acorn.js:603:10)
    at Parser.pp$3.parseExprAtom (D:\tessact-client-2\node_modules\webpack\node_modules\acorn\dist\acorn.js:1822:12)
    at Parser.pp$3.parseExprSubscripts (D:\tessact-client-2\node_modules\webpack\node_modules\acorn\dist\acorn.js:1715:21)
    at Parser.pp$3.parseMaybeUnary (D:\tessact-client-2\node_modules\webpack\node_modules\acorn\dist\acorn.js:1692:19)
    at Parser.pp$3.parseExprOps (D:\tessact-client-2\node_modules\webpack\node_modules\acorn\dist\acorn.js:1637:21)
    at Parser.pp$3.parseMaybeConditional (D:\tessact-client-2\node_modules\webpack\node_modules\acorn\dist\acorn.js:1620:21)
    at Parser.pp$3.parseMaybeAssign (D:\tessact-client-2\node_modules\webpack\node_modules\acorn\dist\acorn.js:1597:21)
    at Parser.pp$3.parseExprList (D:\tessact-client-2\node_modules\webpack\node_modules\acorn\dist\acorn.js:2165:22)
    at Parser.pp$3.parseSubscripts (D:\tessact-client-2\node_modules\webpack\node_modules\acorn\dist\acorn.js:1741:35)
    at Parser.pp$3.parseExprSubscripts (D:\tessact-client-2\node_modules\webpack\node_modules\acorn\dist\acorn.js:1718:17)
    at Parser.pp$3.parseMaybeUnary (D:\tessact-client-2\node_modules\webpack\node_modules\acorn\dist\acorn.js:1692:19)
    at Parser.pp$3.parseExprOps (D:\tessact-client-2\node_modules\webpack\node_modules\acorn\dist\acorn.js:1637:21)
    at Parser.pp$3.parseMaybeConditional (D:\tessact-client-2\node_modules\webpack\node_modules\acorn\dist\acorn.js:1620:21)
    at Parser.pp$3.parseMaybeAssign (D:\tessact-client-2\node_modules\webpack\node_modules\acorn\dist\acorn.js:1597:21)
    at Parser.pp$3.parseExpression (D:\tessact-client-2\node_modules\webpack\node_modules\acorn\dist\acorn.js:1573:21)
 @ multi main
  -- client bundled.
Hash: d2622522a127e8235b84
Version: webpack 1.13.3
Time: 735ms
           Asset     Size  Chunks             Chunk Names
server-bundle.js  65.5 kB       0  [emitted]  main
  -- server:watch bundled.
[23:35:26] Finished 'bundle' after 755 ms
[23:35:26] Starting 'start:server'...
Starting Node Server...
[23:35:26] Finished 'start:server' after 70 ms
[23:35:26] Starting 'watch:sync'...
webpack built 6444932e1774038f4027 in 128ms
Hash: 6444932e1774038f4027
Version: webpack 1.13.3
Time: 128ms
         Asset    Size  Chunks       Chunk Names
main-bundle.js  102 kB       0       main

ERROR in ./src/client/index.js
Module parse failed: D:\tessact-client-2\src\client\index.js Unexpected token (78:1)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
SyntaxError: Unexpected token (78:1)
    at Parser.pp$4.raise (D:\tessact-client-2\node_modules\webpack\node_modules\acorn\dist\acorn.js:2221:15)
    at Parser.pp.unexpected (D:\tessact-client-2\node_modules\webpack\node_modules\acorn\dist\acorn.js:603:10)
    at Parser.pp$3.parseExprAtom (D:\tessact-client-2\node_modules\webpack\node_modules\acorn\dist\acorn.js:1822:12)
    at Parser.pp$3.parseExprSubscripts (D:\tessact-client-2\node_modules\webpack\node_modules\acorn\dist\acorn.js:1715:21)
    at Parser.pp$3.parseMaybeUnary (D:\tessact-client-2\node_modules\webpack\node_modules\acorn\dist\acorn.js:1692:19)
    at Parser.pp$3.parseExprOps (D:\tessact-client-2\node_modules\webpack\node_modules\acorn\dist\acorn.js:1637:21)
    at Parser.pp$3.parseMaybeConditional (D:\tessact-client-2\node_modules\webpack\node_modules\acorn\dist\acorn.js:1620:21)
    at Parser.pp$3.parseMaybeAssign (D:\tessact-client-2\node_modules\webpack\node_modules\acorn\dist\acorn.js:1597:21)
    at Parser.pp$3.parseExprList (D:\tessact-client-2\node_modules\webpack\node_modules\acorn\dist\acorn.js:2165:22)
    at Parser.pp$3.parseSubscripts (D:\tessact-client-2\node_modules\webpack\node_modules\acorn\dist\acorn.js:1741:35)
    at Parser.pp$3.parseExprSubscripts (D:\tessact-client-2\node_modules\webpack\node_modules\acorn\dist\acorn.js:1718:17)
    at Parser.pp$3.parseMaybeUnary (D:\tessact-client-2\node_modules\webpack\node_modules\acorn\dist\acorn.js:1692:19)
    at Parser.pp$3.parseExprOps (D:\tessact-client-2\node_modules\webpack\node_modules\acorn\dist\acorn.js:1637:21)
    at Parser.pp$3.parseMaybeConditional (D:\tessact-client-2\node_modules\webpack\node_modules\acorn\dist\acorn.js:1620:21)
    at Parser.pp$3.parseMaybeAssign (D:\tessact-client-2\node_modules\webpack\node_modules\acorn\dist\acorn.js:1597:21)
    at Parser.pp$3.parseExpression (D:\tessact-client-2\node_modules\webpack\node_modules\acorn\dist\acorn.js:1573:21)
 @ multi main
webpack: Failed to compile.
[23:35:26] [nodemon] 1.11.0
[23:35:26] [nodemon] to restart at any time, enter `rs`
[23:35:26] [nodemon] watching: build/server-bundle.js
[23:35:26] [nodemon] starting `node --debug --inspect build/server-bundle.js`
Server Restarted: Reloading BrowserSync.
[tessact: ] Reloading Browsers...
Debugger listening on port 9229.
Warning: This is an experimental feature and could change at any time.
To start debugging, open the following URL in Chrome:
    chrome-devtools://devtools/remote/serve_file/@60cd6e859b9f557d2312f5bf532f6aec5f284980/inspector.html?experiments=true&v8only=true&ws=localhost:9229/ab7077df-5cf6-4b42-9937-75ec7
873204f
[tessact: ] Proxying: http://localhost:4200
[tessact: ] Access URLs:
 --------------------------------------
       Local: http://localhost:3000
    External: http://192.168.152.1:3000
 --------------------------------------
          UI: http://localhost:3001
 UI External: http://192.168.152.1:3001
 --------------------------------------
[tessact: ] Watching files...
[23:35:28] Finished 'watch:sync' after 2.22 s
[23:35:28] Starting 'watch:assets'...
[23:35:28] Finished 'watch:assets' after 20 ms
[23:35:28] Finished 'build:watch' after 3.69 s
[23:35:28] Starting 'default'...
[23:35:28] Finished 'default' after 1.98 μs
  tessact:db DBERROR:  connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:3306 +0ms
ServerStartupError:  { Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:3306
    at Object.exports._errnoException (util.js:1026:11)
    at exports._exceptionWithHostPort (util.js:1049:20)
    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1085:14)
    at Protocol._enqueue (D:\tessact-client-2\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Protocol.js:141:48)
    at Protocol.handshake (D:\tessact-client-2\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Protocol.js:52:41)
    at Connection.connect (D:\tessact-client-2\node_modules\mysql\lib\Connection.js:136:18)
    at D:\tessact-client-2\build\webpack:\D:\tessact-client-2\src\server\db.js:26:14
From previous event:
    at initDB (D:\tessact-client-2\build\webpack:\D:\tessact-client-2\src\server\db.js:25:9)
    at Object.defineProperty.value (D:\tessact-client-2\build\webpack:\D:\tessact-client-2\src\server\app.js:27:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (D:\tessact-client-2\build\webpack:\webpack\bootstrap d2622522a127e8235b84:19:1)
    at Object.<anonymous> (D:\tessact-client-2\build\server-bundle.js:48:19)
    at __webpack_require__ (D:\tessact-client-2\build\webpack:\webpack\bootstrap d2622522a127e8235b84:19:1)
    at D:\tessact-client-2\build\webpack:\webpack\bootstrap d2622522a127e8235b84:39:1
    at Object.<anonymous> (D:\tessact-client-2\build\server-bundle.js:44:10)
    at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
    at Module.runMain (module.js:604:10)
    at run (bootstrap_node.js:394:7)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:149:9)
    at bootstrap_node.js:509:3
  code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
  errno: 'ECONNREFUSED',
  syscall: 'connect',
  address: '127.0.0.1',
  port: 3306,
  fatal: true }
[23:35:29] [nodemon] clean exit - waiting for changes before restart
```

This is the script in my package.json

```
    "scripts": {
        "postinstall": "set NODE_ENV=production node ./node_modules/.bin/gulp build:prod",
        "start": "node build/server-bundle.js",
        "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
      },
```

And this is my client.config file

```
var path = require('path');
var webpack = require('webpack');

var DIRS = require('./dirs.js');

var stylus = require('stylus');
var nib = require('nib');
var axis = require('axis');
var rupture = require('rupture');
var bootstrap = require('bootstrap-styl');
var ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');

var IS_PROD = process.env.NODE_ENV === "production";
var config = {
    devtool: IS_PROD ? false : 'eval',
    debug: !IS_PROD,
    cache: true,
    root: DIRS.ROOT,
    watchOptions: {
        ignored: /node_modules/
    },
    entry: {
        main: [ DIRS.SRC_CLIENT + '/index.js' ]
    },
    output: {
        path: DIRS.BUILD_PUBLIC,
        publicPath: '/public/',
        filename: '[name]-bundle.js'
    },
    resolve: {
        modulesDirectories: [ DIRS.SRC_CLIENT, 'node_modules'],
        extensions: ['', '.webpack.js', '.web.js', '.js', '.styl', '.css'],
        alias: {
            'video-js': 'video.js/dist/video.js'
        }
    },
    module: {
        loaders: [
            {test: /\.json$/, loader: 'json', exclude: /node_modules/},
            {test: /\.js$/, 
                loader: 'babel', 
                exclude: /(node_modules|rangeslider\.js)/,
                include: [ DIRS.SRC_CLIENT ],
                query: {
                    cacheDirectory: true,
                    env: { 
                        development: {
                            presets: ['react-hmre']
                        }
                    } 
                }
            },
            {
                test: /\.styl$/, 
                loader: [ 
                    'isomorphic-style-loader',
                    'css?sourceMap&localIdentName=[name]_[local]_[hash:base64:3]',
                    'stylus?sourceMap'
                ].join('!')
            },
            {
                test: /\.html$/,
                loader: 'html-loader?attrs[]=video:src'
            }, {
                test: /\.mp4$/,
                loader: 'url?limit=10000&mimetype=video/mp4'
            },
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                loader: 'style-loader!css-loader'
            },
            {
                test: /\.woff(2)?(\?v=[0-9]\.[0-9]\.[0-9])?$/,
                loader: 'url-loader?limit=100000&mimetype=application/font-woff'
            },
            {
                test: /\.(ttf|eot|svg)(\?v=[0-9]\.[0-9]\.[0-9])?$/,
                loader: 'file-loader'
            },{
                test: /\.(png|jpg|jpeg|gif)$/,
                loader: 'url-loader',
                query: {
                  name: IS_PROD ? '[hash].[ext]' : '[path][name].[ext]?[hash]',
                  limit: 10000,
                }
            }
        ]
    },
    plugins: [
        new webpack.DefinePlugin({
            __DEV__: !IS_PROD,
            __SERVER__: false,
            "process.env.NODE_ENV": (IS_PROD ? JSON.stringify("production") : JSON.stringify("development"))
        }),
        new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
            React: 'react',
            jQuery: 'jquery',
            $: 'jquery',
            videojs: 'video.js',
            'window.videojs': 'video.js'
        }),
        new webpack.ContextReplacementPlugin(/moment[\/\\]locale$/, /en/)
    ],
    stylus: {
        use: [nib(), axis(), rupture(), bootstrap()],
        import: path.resolve(__dirname, '../src/stylus/index.styl'),
        error: IS_PROD,
        compress: IS_PROD,
        'include css': true
    }
};

if (IS_PROD){
    // console.log('--- CLIENT:PRODUCTION_MODE ---');
    config.entry.vendors = [
        'react', 'react-dom', 'react-router',
        'lodash', 'core-js', 'moment', 'jquery', 'bluebird',
        'redux', 'react-redux', 'react-router-redux',
        'history'
    ];

    config.plugins = config.plugins.concat([  
        new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
            name: 'vendors',
            filename: 'vendors-bundle.js'
        }),
        new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({
            compress: {warnings: false},
            comments: false
        }),
        new webpack.optimize.AggressiveMergingPlugin(),
    ]);
} else {
    config.entry.main.unshift('webpack-hot-middleware/client')
    config.plugins = config.plugins.concat([
        new webpack.DllReferencePlugin({
            context: DIRS.SRC_CLIENT,
            manifest: require(DIRS.BUILD_PUBLIC + '/dll/vendor-manifest.json')
        }),
        new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
        new webpack.NoErrorsPlugin()
    ]);
}


module.exports = config;
```

client/index.js

```
import _ from 'lodash'
import React    from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'

import Promise from 'bluebird'

import createHistory  from 'history/lib/createBrowserHistory'
import Router from 'react-router/lib/Router'
import RouterContext from 'react-router/lib/RouterContext'
import match  from 'react-router/lib/match'
import useRouterHistory from 'react-router/lib/useRouterHistory'
import injectTapEventPlugin from 'react-tap-event-plugin';


import MuiThemeProvider from 'material-ui/styles/MuiThemeProvider';
import getMuiTheme from 'material-ui/styles/getMuiTheme';
import theme from 'utils/theme'

import { syncHistoryWithStore } from 'react-router-redux'

import configureStore, { loadState, saveState, storageSupported } from './store'

import getRoutes from './routes'

import Root from 'containers/Root'
import WithStylesContext from 'utils/withStylesContext'
import $ from 'jquery'
var debug = require('debug')('tessact:client')

window.Promise = Promise;
window.$ = window.jQuery = $;
injectTapEventPlugin();

var browserHistory = useRouterHistory(createHistory)({
    queryKey: false,
    basename: '/'
});

var savedState = loadState()
var initialState = _.merge(window.INITIAL_STATE || {}, savedState)

var store   = configureStore(initialState, browserHistory);
var routes  = getRoutes(store);
var history = syncHistoryWithStore(browserHistory, store, {
  selectLocationState: (state) => state.router
});


const SKIP_PERSIST_KEYS = ['router']    // Do not get saved to localStorage
if (storageSupported()){
    window.localStorage.debug = 'tessact:*';
    store.subscribe(_.throttle(()=> {
        debug('Persisting data to store.')
        var data = store.getState();
        saveState( _.omit(data, ...SKIP_PERSIST_KEYS) )
    }, 2000))
}


const ROOT_CONTAINER = document.getElementById('root');
const onRenderComplete = ()=> {
    console.timeEnd('render');
}

if ( __DEV__ ){
    window._STORE = store;
    window.React = React;
    window.ReactDOM = ReactDOM;
}

let muiTheme = getMuiTheme(theme);
console.time('render');




ReactDOM.render(
    <MuiThemeProvider muiTheme={muiTheme}>
        <Root store={store}>
            <WithStylesContext onInsertCss={styles=> styles._insertCss()}>
                <Router history={history}>
                    {routes}
                </Router>
            </WithStylesContext>
        </Root>
    </MuiThemeProvider>,
    ROOT_CONTAINER,
    onRenderComplete
)
```

Gulp file

```
import gulp   from 'gulp'
import run    from 'run-sequence'
import loadPlugins from 'gulp-load-plugins'


import browserSync from 'browser-sync'
import webpack   from 'webpack'
import webpackDevMiddleware from 'webpack-dev-middleware'
import webpackHotMiddleware from 'webpack-hot-middleware'
import ClientConfig  from './tools/client.config'
import ServerConfig  from './tools/server.config'
import DLLConfig from './tools/dll.config'

import vendorsTask from './copy_task'


const IS_PROD = process.env.NODE_ENV === "production";
var WATCH = false;
var clientBundler;
var serverBundler;

var $ = loadPlugins();

gulp.task('default', ['build:watch']);
gulp.task('build:prod', cb=> {
    WATCH = false;
    run('copy:assets', 'bundle', cb);
});
gulp.task('build:watch', cb=> {
    WATCH = true;
    run('copy:assets', 'bundle:dll', 'bundle', 'start:server', 'watch:sync', 'watch:assets', cb);
});

gulp.task('bundle:dll', cb=> {
    if (IS_PROD)
        return cb();

    var dllBundler = webpack(DLLConfig);

    return new Promise((resolve, reject)=> {
        dllBundler.run((err, stats)=> {
            if (err) {
                return reject(err)
            }
            console.log('DLL Bundled.')
            console.log(stats.toString({colors: true, chunks: false}))
            resolve()
        });
    })
});

gulp.task('bundle', cb => {
    var count = 0;
    clientBundler = webpack(ClientConfig)
    serverBundler = webpack(ServerConfig);
    const bundleComplete = (msg) => (err, stats)=> {
        if (err)
            throw new gutil.PluginError(msg + ':bundle', err)
        console.log( stats.toString({ colors: true, chunks: false }) );
        console.log( `  -- ${msg} bundled.`);
        if (++count === 2) cb();
    }

    clientBundler.run(bundleComplete('client'));
    WATCH
        ? serverBundler.watch(750, bundleComplete('server:watch'))
        : serverBundler.run(bundleComplete('server'))
});

gulp.task('start:server', cb=> {
    console.log('Starting Node Server...');
    $.nodemon({
        script: 'build/server-bundle.js',
        watch: ['build/server-bundle.js'],
        ext: 'js',
        ignore: ['!build/public', '!build/vendor', 'src/client'],
        env: Object.assign({NODE_ENV: 'development', DEBUG: 'tessact:*'}, process.env),
        nodeArgs: ['--debug', '--inspect']
    }).on('start', cb=>{
        console.log('Server Restarted: Reloading BrowserSync.');
        browserSync.reload();
    });
    cb();
});

gulp.task('watch:sync', cb=> {
    process.on('exit', () => browserSync.exit());
    browserSync({
        logPrefix: 'tessact: ',
        open: false, notify: true,
        port: (process.env.BS_PORT || 3000),
        proxy: {
            target: 'localhost:4200',
            middleware: [
                webpackDevMiddleware(clientBundler, {
                    publicPath: ClientConfig.output.publicPath,
                    stats: {colors: true, chunks: false}
                }),
                webpackHotMiddleware(clientBundler)
            ]
        },
        files: [
            'build/public/**/*.css',
            '!build/public/**/*.js'
        ]
    }, cb);
});

gulp.task('copy:vendors', vendorsTask);
gulp.task('copy:assets', cb=> {
    run('copy:vendors', 'copy:views', 'copy:public', cb);
});
gulp.task('copy:views', cb=> {
    return (
        gulp.src('./src/server/views/**/*.jade')
            .pipe($.changed('./build/views'))
            .pipe($.size({title: 'copied views', pretty: true}))
            .pipe( gulp.dest('./build/views'))
    )
});
gulp.task('copy:public', cb=> {
    return (
        gulp.src('./src/public/**/*.*')
            .pipe($.changed('./build/public/'))
            .pipe($.size({title: 'copied public', pretty: true}))
            .pipe(gulp.dest('./build/public/'))
    )
});
gulp.task('watch:assets', cb=> {
    gulp.watch('./src/server/views/**/*.jade', {interval: 1000}, ['copy:views']);
    gulp.watch('./src/public/**/*.*', {interval: 1000}, ['copy:public']);
    cb();
});
```

Comment: can you show me your client/index.js

Comment: I assume you have a similar issue as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48347011/webpack-error-from-uglifyjs-when-creating-production-assets/48347186#48347186

Comment: @Dipakchavda added client/index.js

Comment: @connexo how is it similar to mine?

Comment: `Module parse failed: D:\tessact-client-2\src\client\index.js Unexpected token (78:1)` It looks like jsx isn't being parsed correctly in your index.js file.

Comment: Any solutions for that?

Answer (score 0):

**Edit:** Add different Configuration

The issue is likely the loader that transpiles the jsx. Make sure you have all of the babel dev-depencies

`npm install --save-dev babel-loader babel-core babel-preset-env`

Then

```
// There wasn't a lot on the configuration for older versions of Webpack
// The new version which should be compatible with the older version wraps loaders in a rules array option
rules: [
    {test: /\.js$/,
        loader: 'babel-loader',// use the babel-loader npm package loader
        exclude: /(node_modules|rangeslider\.js)/,
        include: [ DIRS.SRC_CLIENT ],
        query: {
            cacheDirectory: true,
            env: {
                development: {
                    presets: ['@babel/preset-env']
                }
            }
        }
    }
    // then add all the other loaders
]
```

Also if you don't have a .babelrc file add on and use:

```
{
    "presets": ["es2015","react"]
}
```

Comment: still the same issue

Comment: added. Have a look

Comment: I added a different configuration, I'm pretty sure babel isn't being configured correctly to transpile

Comment: same issue. No progress